# PayPal initialization error

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using the PayPal MPL library and have been getting this error during initialization the past 3 days:

```
Checking Error********************
Posting Error: -1
```

It is happening in my PayPal demo project as well the project that they provided with the PayPal MPL SDK. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Are you using Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: i am using Objective-C.